# How to receive focus when clicking on the background of a stackpanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have a UserControl which contains a Label and a TextBox. Both are placed inside a stackpanel which is placed in a border.

I now want to receive an Event when the mouse clicks somewere inside the stackpanel or the border. I tried several things, as using transparent Backgrounds, different Events like ismousedirectlyover etc.

Is there a way i can solve this?

Comment: If you could put your code it would help us to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by capturing the mousedown event inside your textbox, your label and your stackpanel and bind them all directly to the same method, you will allways get the mousedown event independent on where you clicked.
You can also try to set the

```
Panel.Zindex
```

property to a higher number in the stackpanel and then only capture the mousedown event on it.

Comment: Thank you.. i was only looking for GotFocus I forgot totally about the OnClick Event. This is working even without the ZIndex changing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add an handler for the `MouseLeftButtonDown` to the border:

```
<Border MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
        <TextBox x:Name="Text" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

2) Set the focus manually to the `TextBox`:

```
private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Text.Focus();
}
```

make sure to set the background of the stackpanel to transparent.